# How to overwrite a duplicate observation

Tags: stata

I conducted a phone survey and here is the prototype of my dataset:

```
var1    var2

6666    1
6666    2
7676    2
7676    1
8876    1
8876    2
89898   1
89898   2
9999    1
9999    2
5656    1
5656    2
2323    1
2323    2
9876    1
7654    1
```

`var1` is the unique identifier for each case in my survey (in this case, phone numbers).

`var2` is the outcome of the survey: 1 (successful), 2 (not successful).

I want keep the observations for each `var1` whose `var2 == 1`, yet retaining the observations for each `var1` whose`var2 == 2` if there is no another case where `var2 == 1`.

I have tried

```
duplicates drop var1 if var2 == 2, force
```

but I am not getting the desired output

Answer (score 1):

The question is wrongly  titled: you don't want to overwrite anything.

Your syntax doesn't work as you wish because it is not what you want. You are asking whether there are duplicates of `var1 if var2 == 2` and that command pays no attention whatsoever to observations for which `var2 == 1`.

Your example includes no observations for which `var2 == 2` but there is no corresponding observation with `var2 == 1`. I have added one such.

Here's one way of meeting your goal. I show in passing that the `duplicates` command you have does nothing for this example; nor would it be expected to do anything.

```
. clear 

. input  var1    var2

          var1       var2
  1.     6666        1
  2.     6666        2
  3.     7676        2
  4.     7676        1
  5.     8876        1
  6.     8876        2
  7.     89898       1
  8.     89898       2
  9.     9999        1
 10.     9999        2
 11.     5656        1
 12.     5656        2
 13.     2323        1
 14.     2323        2
 15.     9876        1
 16.     7654        1
 17.     42      2 
 18. end 

. duplicates list var1 if var2 == 2 

Duplicates in terms of var1

(0 observations are duplicates)

. bysort var1 (var2) : assert _N == 1 | _N == 2 

. by var1 : drop if _n == 2 & var2[2] == 2 
(7 observations deleted)

. list, sepby(var1) 

     +--------------+
     |  var1   var2 |
     |--------------|
  1. |    42      2 |
     |--------------|
  2. |  2323      1 |
     |--------------|
  3. |  5656      1 |
     |--------------|
  4. |  6666      1 |
     |--------------|
  5. |  7654      1 |
     |--------------|
  6. |  7676      1 |
     |--------------|
  7. |  8876      1 |
     |--------------|
  8. |  9876      1 |
     |--------------|
  9. |  9999      1 |
     |--------------|
 10. | 89898      1 |
     +--------------+
```

Another way to do it would be

```
. bysort var1 (var2) : keep if _n == 1 & var2[2] == 2
```

In fact

```
. bysort var1 (var2): keep if _n == 1
```

keeps observations with `var2 == 1` if there are any and otherwise will also keep singletons with `var2 == 2`.

The hidden assumptions seem to include at most two observations for each distinct `var1`. Note the use of `assert` for checking assumptions about the dataset.

Comment: If the values of 2 that i have in var2 were to be 0 or any other number, the command does almost the opposite of what I desire to achieve.

Comment: If you believe the code doesn't solve your problem, or a new problem, edit your question to show the difficulty with data and code example.